# Windows 7 Device Stage Experience for Virtual Printers?

Tags: windows-7

I am working on a virtual printer that converts various files to PDF format.

As you know Microsoft introduced Device Stage Experience in Windows 7, which is a nice way to customize the user's experience when interacting with your device. I have downloaded and installed their development kit, only to quickly find out that everything relates to the hardware ID of your device.

Is there any way to create a Device Stage Experience for a virtual device (like our virtual printer, which has a null hardware id)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Windows Device Experience development pack.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463154) as far as I know you can create a Device Stage for any device. The fact it is virtual is known only to you as the dev of the driver. Windows does not treat them differently.

There's also a good o[verview on how to do it here](http://www.microsoft.com/winme/0905/1000685/Device_Stage/default.html).

Answer (score 0):

WinPcap can give you some hint, you can get the source [here](http://www.winpcap.org/install/bin/PacketCE.zip).
It creates a virtual ethernet adapter to catch the inbound / outbound packets. You can pick the logic from it.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot see the device installed in Devices and Printers, from where you open the Device Stage view for the installed devices. Any trick I should know?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to have your virtual device have a non-null hardware ID. Which would doubtless create other issues - you'd need an increased level of hardware faking, no doubt.

Martyn